# Bootstrap Switch show/hide table columns - initial configuration & value storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a table, with which I need to be able to sort and filter (form submit) as well as being able to show and hide columns. I have a simple checkbox that does nothing but toggle the columns. I have been able to get that to work properly, but my problem now is that I need to save the state throughout the entire page lifecycle -- which doesn’t happen.

The basic column show/hide is in the page itself, right after the table:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('input[name="columnControl"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    if (state) {
      $("th.status").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td.status").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("th.information").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td.information").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td#p1").attr('colspan', 4);
      $("td#p2").attr('colspan', 6);
      localStorage.setItem('columnControl', 'true');
    } else {
      $("th.status").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td.status").addClass("columnHide");
      $("th.information").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td.information").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td#p1").attr('colspan', 2);
      $("td#p2").attr('colspan', 3);
      localStorage.setItem('columnControl', 'false');
    }
  });
</script>
}
```

So  please note: the above DOES WORK, at least in terms of showing and hiding the columns.

Now, the best method I have found so far for saving information through the page cycle is via the localstorage setting, as seen in the code above. This works splendidly for tabs on other pages, but I have been unable to get it to work for my table and bootstrap switch.

Specifically:

- On page load, I want the switch to be conditional on the state of the localstorage setting. If it is true or false, the switch needs to be at the appropriate setting, and the appropriate classes need to be set for the columns. If there is no localstorage content (no True or False stored), I need the switch to be ON (true) and certain classes set (a default case).
- On form submit (a GET, not a POST), I need to have the switch and all applied classes to remain the same as they were, and to NOT revert to a default case.
- If the user leaves the page and returns to it, the switch and classes should remain at their last state and to not revert to the default.

The best I have been able to come up with is this:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var columnState = localStorage.getItem('columnControl'); //grab the localstorage value, if any
  if (columnState) { //does the localstorage value even exist?
    $('input[name="columnControl"]').bootstrapSwitch('setState', columnState); //if localstorage exists, set bootstrap switch state based off of localstorage value
    if (columnState == 'true') { //if localstorage value == true
      $("th.status").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td.status").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("th.information").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td.information").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td#p1").attr('colspan', 4); //set tfoot colspans
      $("td#p2").attr('colspan', 6);
    } else { //if localstorage value == false
      $("th.status").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td.status").addClass("columnHide");
      $("th.information").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td.information").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td#p1").attr('colspan', 2); //set tfoot colspans
      $("td#p2").attr('colspan', 3);
    }
  } else { //if localstorage value doesn't exist, set default values
    $('input[name="columnControl"]').bootstrapSwitch('setState', true);
    $("th.information").addClass("columnHide");
    $("td.information").addClass("columnHide");
  }
});

  $('input[name="columnControl"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    … first script, above …
  });
</script>
}
```

The actual Bootstrap Switch is initialized by a global JS file, via

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").bootstrapSwitch(); // checkbox toggle
```

which appears in the head of the webpage.

I have two groups of columns, `information` and `status` which comprise 80% of the columns between them. Three columns have no flag for being hidden or unhidden, because they are meant to be displayed at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for test if the local storage exist use :

```
columnState === null
```

You just need to fire the switchChange event after define the default value

**Full exemple :**

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('input[name="columnControl"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    if (state) {
      $("th.status").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td.status").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("th.information").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td.information").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td#p1").attr('colspan', 4);
      $("td#p2").attr('colspan', 6);
      localStorage.setItem('columnControl', true);
    } else {
      $("th.status").addClass("columnHide");
      $("td.status").addClass("columnHide");
      $("th.information").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td.information").removeClass("columnHide");
      $("td#p1").attr('colspan', 2);
      $("td#p2").attr('colspan', 3);
      localStorage.setItem('columnControl', false);
    }
  });
 var columnState = localStorage.getItem('columnControl'); //grab the localstorage value, if any
  if (columnState === null) { //does the localstorage value even exist?
    columnState = true //if localstorage value doesn't exist, set default values
  } 

  $('input[name="columnControl"]').bootstrapSwitch('setState', columnState);


</script>
}
```

Comment: I had to rework your solution some to extend it to all the details I needed, but what you gave me worked great. One of the problems I had was a misinterpretation of Bootstrap Switch, in that the latest version no longer made use of `setState` but just `state`. However your rearranging of my content was what made everything work. Thank you!!